# In langchain embeddings using PGVector if the user asks question and it matched 2 files. I need to show the response with the latest uploaded file

Tags: python-3.x, python-embedding, py-langchain, pgvector

In langchain embeddings using PGVector if the user asks question and it matched 2 files. I need to show the response with the latest uploaded file. In my embeddings when a file is uploaded i am storing it as timestamp_file_name. Please let me know on how to retrieve the latest file in python while querying.

While uploading and embedding the file itself i was storing as timestamp with file name so i did tried getting those details. And also when querying if there are 2 files matching comparing the file name and the timestamp and retrieving those datas. Not worked for me.

I want to show the latest uploaded file when 2 files get matched. Is there any option available in langchain-python